# How to Install gimp 2.8 on ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, apt, software-installation, ppa, gimp

I installed gimp 2.9.3,on my Ubuntu 15.10 but I saw that this version of Gimp have some bugs with tools like Cage Transform tool.

I google the problem and after a while I decide to uninstall Gimp 2.9.3. and install Gimp 2.8 since it does not have this bugs.

I tried to install Gimp 2.8 via this commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

But this commands installed my the newest version of Gimp.

How can I install Gimp 2.8?

When I type `apt-cache policy gimp`:

```
gimp: 
Instaŀlat: (cap)
  Candidat:  2.9.3~5-0w1~ppa
  Taula de versió:
     2.9.3~5-0w1~ppa 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp-edge/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.8.14-1ubuntu2 0
        500 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
```

When I type `grep -r '^[^#]*ppa' /etc/apt/*`:

```
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/otto-kesselgulasch-ubuntu-gimp-edge-wily.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp-edge/ubuntu wily main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/otto-kesselgulasch-ubuntu-gimp-edge-wily.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp-edge/ubuntu wily main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/chris-lea-ubuntu-node_js-vivid.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu vivid main
grep: /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg: S’ha denegat el permís
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Completely remove Gimp 2.9 and completely remove the PPA.
Then install Gimp 2.8 from the official Ubuntu repositories.
Open a terminal and execute the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge gimp
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge 
sudo ppa-purge ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp  
sudo ppa-purge ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp-edge
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

Comment: +1 but I thought the idea of `ppa-purge` was that it gracefully rolled back to the repo version *without* needing to manually remove / update / install the package? Isn't that strictly only necessary if you *manually* remove the ppa (using `apt-add-repository --remove` or editing sources.list)?

Comment: It installs me Gimp version 2.9.3, not 2.8

Comment: @Xalsar please edit your question to include the output of `apt-cache policy gimp` and `grep -r '^[^#]*ppa' /etc/apt/*`

Comment: @Xalsar : Did you install Gimp 2.9 manually or did you add another PPA to install the Gimp 2.9 packages ?

Comment: I install Gimp via PPA, I think

Comment: @Xalsar : The output from apt-cache policy gimp and grep -r '^[^#]*ppa' /etc/apt/* shows that you have  ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp-edge in sources.list.d ! :) I updated the answer how to remove the PPA. :)

Comment: and now how can I acces to gimp?

Comment: @Xalsar : Press the Windows key, type Gimp, then click on the icon ... or open a terminal and type gimp. :)